# css in reactjs app not being applied - logic based on positional logic

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to troubleshoot why a specific css class is not being applied to a button in my reactjs app. I can't seem to find the error - i'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Here's the css definition:

```
.button-group-right {
    justify-content: flex-end;

    .toolbox-button {
        &:nth-child(2) {
            .toolbox-icon {
                background-color: $hangupColor;
                border: 1px solid $hangupColor;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
        
                &:hover {
                    background-color: $hangupColor;
                }

                svg {
                    fill: #fff;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see, if the button is the has an index value of 2 it's supposed to apply this style.
(basically apply a red background)

I added a console debug statement to print the contents of the array to prove the hangup button is index 2:

```
(3) ["overflowmenu", "tileview", "hangup"]
0: "overflowmenu"
1: "tileview"
2: "hangup"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The rendered HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="button-group-right">

    (div for first 2 buttons removed for simplifying code review)

    <div aria-label="Leave the call" class="toolbox-button">
        <div>
            <div class="toolbox-icon">
                <div class="jj-icon">
                    <svg height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                        <path></path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you see where I've strayed, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Comment: which element do you want to apply `red` background?

Comment: to the toolbox-icon DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `nth-child` means. It's not about the index of nestedness, it's about the placement in the parent element.

for example in the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

the second and third `p` will get a red background, because they're the second child in their parents (`second p` is the second child in div and `third p` is the second child of the body element).

so if you want to pass styles to `toolbox-icon div` you gotto do:

```
 .toolbox-button {
            .toolbox-icon {
                background-color: $hangupColor;
                border: 1px solid $hangupColor;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
        
                &:hover {
                    background-color: $hangupColor;
                }

                svg {
                    fill: #fff;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: oh boy. that made so much sense.  thanks!  problem fixed.